# Write pandas dataframe to dynamodb

Tags: pandas, amazon-dynamodb

I have a panda dataframe that looks like this (with hundreds of rows):

```
        lat     lon       timezone       timestamp              temp    feels_like  humidity    pressure
 0  52.517  13.3889   Europe/Berlin      08/01/2021 00:00:00    17.82   17.46           69          1005
```

I would like to save my panda dataframe to dynamoDB.

I have already set up a dynamodb client:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='')
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')
```

the table has the following keys:

```
Primary partition key   pk_id (String)
Primary sort key        sk    (String)
```

and it has 2 Indexes with the following keys:

```
Partition key   gsi_1_pk (String)
Sort key        gsi_1_sk (String)
Partition key   gsi_2_pk (String)
Sort key        gsi_2_sk (String)
```

The fields from the dataframe shall be assigned as following:

```
pk_id (String)       lat
sk    (String)       lon
gsi_1_pk (String)    timezone
gsi_1_sk (String)    timestamp
gsi_2_pk (String)    temp
gsi_2_sk (String)    feels_like
```

Now I'm wondering how I can write the content of the Dataframe to my Table in DynamoDB.

I have tried this but to no avail:

```
def put_item_in_database():
   datadict = df_select_hist2.T.to_dict().values()
   database = dynamodb
   table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')
   table.put_item(Item = datadict)
```

Merci A

Comment: Does AWS Data Wrangler do what you want? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/main/tutorials/028%20-%20DynamoDB.ipynb It claims to be "Pandas on AWS".

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it throws to many errors and I’d like to do it without another layer on it to understand the mechanics how to do it.